# How to write a __repr__ when one of the inputs is a dataframe?

Tags: python, repr

I have a class that takes a pandas dataframe as one of parameters. I've not been very good at adding `__repr__` to my code so now I'm trying to go back and add to all the existing codebase. But here I run into the issue:

```
import pandas as pd

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, data: pd.DataFrame, some_val: str):
        self.data = data
        self.some_val = val

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Foo(data={self.data}, some_val={self.some_val})'
```

So in this example if I call `repr()` on an instance of my class I will get something like:

```
Out[7]: 'Foo(data=       xcentre   ycentre  ...
n99996     99996  316065.0  295205.0  ...  undef -99.0 
      undef\n99997     99997  316075.0  295205.0  ...  undef -99.0
       undef\n99998     99998  316065.0  295215.0  ...  undef -99.0 
      undef\n99999     99999  316075.0  295215.0  ...  undef -99.0
       undef\n\n[100000 rows x 121 columns], some_val='blabla')'
```

It is also no surprise I get syntax errors when I try to run `eval()` on it.

So how should I correctly use `__repr__` in this case?

Comment: Well how else would you create an instance of a dataframe from scratch? Generate the same string and that's it...

Comment: From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__): *"If at all possible, this should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value (given an appropriate environment). If this is not possible, a string of the form <...some useful description...> should be returned. [...] This is typically used for debugging, so it is important that the representation is information-rich and unambiguous."* If you can't make it executable Python code, just make it "information-rich and unambiguous".